# Spring boot upload form data and file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, multipartform-data

I am making a spring boot REST application. I am trying to make a multipart form upload controller which will handle a form data and a file upload together. This is my controller code at the moment :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Content-Type=multipart/form-data")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createNewObjectWithImage(
            /*@RequestParam(value="file", required=true) MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam(value="param_name_1", required=true) final String param_name_1,
            @RequestParam(value="param_name_2", required=true) final String param_name_2,
            @RequestParam(value="param_name_3", required=true) final String param_name_3,
            @RequestParam(value="param_name_4", required=true) final String param_name_4,
            @RequestParam(value="param_name_5", required=true) final String param_name_5*/
            @ModelAttribute ModelDTO model,
            BindingResult result) throws MyRestPreconditionsException {

        //ModelDTO model = new ModelDTO(param_name_1, param_name_2, param_name_3, param_name_4, param_name_5);

        modelValidator.validate(model, result);
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            MyRestPreconditionsException ex = new MyRestPreconditionsException(
                    "Model creation error",
                    "Some of the elements in the request are missing or invalid");
            ex.getErrors().addAll(
                    result.getFieldErrors().stream().map(f -> f.getField()+" - "+f.getDefaultMessage()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            throw ex;
        }
// at the moment, model has a MultipartFile property
        //model.setImage(file);
        modelServiceImpl.addNew(model);
    }
```

I have tried both with the @ModelAttribute annotation and sending request parameters, but both of these methods have failed.

This is the request i am sending :

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="mint.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\Lazaruss\Desktop\mint.jpg*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”param_name_1”

string_value_1
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”param_name_2”

string_value_2
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”param_name_3”

string_value_3
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”param_name_4”

string_value_4
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”param_name_5”

string_value_5
---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

My application is stateless, and uses spring security with authorities.
In my security package, i have included the AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer class

```
public class SecurityApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
            insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
        }
    }
```

I also use a StandardServletMultipartResolver in my @Configuration class

And in my WebInitializer, i add this code :

```
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp", 
                3 * 1024 * 1024, 6 * 1024 * 1024, 1 * 512 * 1024);        
apiSR.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfigElement);
```

When i try to use the controller with the commented code (@RequestParams annotations), i get a 404 not found error. 
And when i try to use the controller with the @ModuleAttribute annotation, the model object is empty.

Comment: What is your front-end client? How do you send request.

Comment: I use the Fiddler

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had a similar problem. When you want to send `Object` + `Multipart`. You have to (or at least I don't know other solution) make your controller like that:

```
public void createNewObjectWithImage(@RequestParam("model") String model, @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file)
```

And then: Convert String to your Object using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ModelDTO modelDTO = mapper.readValue(model, ModelDTO.class);
```

And in Postman you can send it like that:
[image]

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer then? :) @Lazaruss

Comment: Solved my problem

Comment: @CrazySabbath It's not hacky at all, what are you even talking about?

Comment: @prettyvoid it's been a while since I wrote this comment, but I think the reason was  having to deserialize object yourself. Overall you are right, it's not hacky. I just didnt quite like the answer, guess I should've picked my words differently.

Comment: what if you have more than one file to upload with the same form, how do go about it?

Comment: @leeCoder i didnt test it, but try to expect a List<Multipart> files in your method, i guess it should work.

Comment: This approach seems to work, but I can't apply custom constraint validators to it.

Answer (score 9):

can receive objects and files

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/catalog/create", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )
public void createNewObjectWithImage(
         @RequestPart ModelTO modelTO,
         @RequestPart MultipartFile image)
```

ModelTO

```java
public class ModelTO {

    private String name;


    public ModelTO() {
        super();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

and curl example:

```
curl -X POST "https://your-url.com/v1/catalog/create" -H  "accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "image=@/pathtoimage/powerRager.jpg;type=image/jpeg" -F "modelTO={\"name\":\"White\"};type=application/json;charset=utf-8"
```

Postman and other software not support send application/json type for form-data params.

Comment: Postman supports sending the content type. Just clic on the ... and check the content type.