# Node js send buffer as multipart form data

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, multer, multipart

I have node js and spring boot apps running on port 3000 and 8080 respectively.

node js:

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const app = express()

var FormData = require('form-data');

app.post('/',  upload.any(), async (req, res) => { 
  
  // step 1
  var myBuffer = req.files[0].buffer;
  const stream = Readable.from(myBuffer.toString()); 
  
  // step 2
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('file', stream) 
  
  // step 3
  let response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/file', form, {
      headers: {
        ...form.getHeaders()
      }
  }) 
  
  res.send(response.data)        
})

const port = 3000

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Let me explain code step by step.

1. Get file content in Buffer and create Readable from it.
2. Create FormData and append stream to it
3. Send form to app on port 8080

spring boot:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/file")
class UploadFile {

    @PostMapping
    fun upload(@ModelAttribute dto: Dto): String {
        return "Hello"
    }
}

class Dto(
    val file: MultipartFile? = null
)
```

This app just accepts file, but it is failing with following error:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Spring application receives **file** in String format and tries to convert it to MultipartFile. I think it should receive file as byte array not as string.

I'm stuck with this buffer and stream help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/catalog/create", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )
public void createNewObjectWithImage(
         @RequestPart ModelTO modelTO,
         @RequestPart MultipartFile image)



public class ModelTO {

    private String name;


    public ModelTO() {
        super();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

This can be your solution to hande the received data. Source [Click HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938056/spring-boot-upload-form-data-and-file)