# 405 Error : multipart/form-data with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a Json string along with multiple files into my Spring Controller, however it would always give me a 405 Method Not Allowed Error, what am I doing wrong?

Javascript Code:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('user', JSON.stringify(userData));

files.forEach(file=> {
  formdata.append('files', file);
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "user/submitForm",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data)
    {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(status + " : " + JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

Controller in Spring:

```
@PostMapping(value= "/submitForm", consumes = { 
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
                        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<?> userRegistration( @RequestPart("user") String user,
            @RequestPart("files") List<MultipartFile> files, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        
        ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser = obj.readValue(user, User.class);
        
        System.out.println("User : \n"+ newUser.toString());
        System.out.println("Files : \n"+ files.toString());
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Some mismatch between Spring method signature and what you're sending. Which you probably realize :-). You might try removing JSON from the controller `consumes`. Not sure how a single method accepting both types will register, and it _sounds_ like you'll always be actually sending multipart?

Comment: @dbreaux I have removed it, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: Also, presumably your application context-root is /user? Maybe grab the actual network request with your browser developer tools and attach the details here. And maybe the Spring binding startup logs as well, where it lists what URLs it's binding to. Bottom line: it looks like the particular combination of POST and Content-type being sent is not what that above Spring method is bound to, so you want to figure out what's different.

Comment: after trying various solutions, I have finally solved it using [the following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938056/spring-boot-upload-form-data-and-file) by Antonio112009.

Comment: I'd add the solution as an Answer and accept it. You can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution that I found from [Antonio112009's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938056/spring-boot-upload-form-data-and-file)

**SOLUTION**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/submitForm")
public ResponseEntity<?> userRegistration(
            @RequestParam("user") String user,
            @RequestParam(value = "files", required = false) List<MultipartFile> files) {

        ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
        User userObj = new User();
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I use another solution, who works as expected and are a bit more flexible from my point of view.

Front-end part is in Typescript.

**Front-end**

```
var formData = new FormData();
options.files.forEach(function (file) {
    formData.append(file.name, file);
});
formData.append("myParam", "coucou");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/rest/upload");
xhr.onload = function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    options.callback("success", options.files.map(function (file) {
        return {
            file: file,
            content: data[file.name]
        };
    }));
}; 
xhr.send(formData);
```

**Back-end (Java Spring)**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
public class UploadController {
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
        // Get param
        Object myParam = request.getParameter("myParam");
        // Get iteretaor on all files
        Iterator<String> iterator = request.getFileNames();
        MultipartFile multipartFile = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            multipartFile = request.getFile(iterator.next());
            final String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            final String fileSize = String.valueOf(multipartFile.getSize());
            // Add logic ....      
        }      
    }
    return new ResponseEntity(true);
}
```